# Obtener archivo en ruta relativa del runnable jar

Tags: java

Estoy hace horas tratando de que me lea un archivo que se encuentra en el mismo directorio que el JAR ejecutable:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("configuracion.json"));
```

Pero ya probé con

1. "./configuracion.json"
2. ".\\configuracion.json"
3. Probé poniendolo en una carpeta "resources" en el root del proyecto y hacer lo de `...getResource("configuracion.json").getPath()` pero tampoco funcionó al exportar, solo durante el debug en Eclipse.

Cuando lo ejecuto en Eclipse (el configuracion.json esta en el root del proyecto) funciona, pero cuando lo exporto a un `Runnable JAR` arroja `FileNotFoundException`.

Si alguien pudiera dar una mano se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar este tipo de situaciones, tengo una función que busca el directorio y comprueba si el path a devolver es el correcto. 
Editado teniendo en cuenta los comentarios

```
 /**
 * Obtenemos la ruta hasta el fichero , habitualmente situado junto al
 * archivo JAR. En caso contrario, estariamos ejecutando desde un IDE y
 * buscaremos el archivo junto al pom.xml y las carpetas target y src.
 *
 * @param filename nombre fle fichero(con extension) a abrir
 * @return Ruta completa hasta el fichero
 * @throws URISyntaxException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String getRutaRecurso(String filename) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    final ProtectionDomain domain;
    final CodeSource source;
    final URL url;
    final URI uri;
    String DirectoryPath;
    String separador_directorios=System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String JarURL;
    File auxiliar;
    domain = Fichero.class.getProtectionDomain();
    source = domain.getCodeSource();
    url = source.getLocation();
    uri = url.toURI();
    JarURL = uri.getPath();
    auxiliar = new File(JarURL);
    //Si es un directorio es que estamos ejecutando desde el IDE. En este caso
    // habrá que buscar el fichero en la carperta  abuela(junto a las carpetas "src" y "target·
    if (auxiliar.isDirectory()) {
        auxiliar = new File(auxiliar.getParentFile().getParentFile().getPath());
        DirectoryPath = auxiliar.getCanonicalPath() + separador_directorios;
    } else {
        JarURL=auxiliar.getCanonicalPath();
        DirectoryPath = JarURL.substring(0, JarURL.lastIndexOf(separador_directorios) + 1);

    }

    System.out.println(DirectoryPath + filename);
    return DirectoryPath + filename;
}
```

En tu código en concreto, sería añadir este de la siguiente forma y teniendo el fichero junto al jar

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(getRutaRecurso("configuracion.json")));
```

Échale un vistazo a ver si te funciona

Comment: Gracias por responder, lamentablemente no me funcionó: cuando ejecuto el JAR en el escritorio trata de buscar el archivo en C:\Users\xxxx\. Cuando debería buscarlo en C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop :S

Comment: Acabo de notar que estaba llamando al archivo por ruta absoluta, es decir, ubicado en C:\Users\ llamaba a mi programa con `java -jar C\Users\xxxx\archivoEjecutable.jar` y por eso arrojaba como que era diferente el entorno

Comment: Definitivamente era eso: me ubiqué con cd en la carpeta donde se encontraba el JAR y se solucionó el problema. Voy a marcar tu respuesta como correcta por tomarte la molestia y por lo útil que resulta para aquellos que usan los archivos dentro de resource. Gracias y saludos!

Comment: Buenas Genarito, disculpas que tarde en contestar, es el momento de viajar y apenas tengo acceso a los ecursos habituales. Como bien comentas, diría que el código que pasé tenía errores. He hecho un pequeño edit para que siempre devuelva la ruta completa en lugar de devolver la relativa desde la posición del JAR. Cuentáme si te funciona (lanzandolo desde la ubicación que desees).

Comment: No hay drama! Mañana lo probaré en la oficina! Gracias y buen viaje!